# Processing-2 PImage get() returns what, exactly?

Tags: processing

So, I know that PImage get(x,y) function returns the color of a pixel at a given coordinate, but can anyone tell me what those numbers mean? They are not 9 digits corresponding to RGB, unless I am missing something.

How can I work with the int numbers returned from a get(x,y) function? I have an image which is a map of data values in raster format. Data are colored into different classes. I want to convert the number I receive from get(x,y) to the actual value within the class.

It would help to know what in the world the return value is...

Answer (score 4):

That number is the colour representation as an integer in RBGA, which is explained all over google. [Here's a sample page](http://www.fayewilliams.com/2011/09/21/simple-programming-bitwise-rgba-values/). If the hexadecimal representation of your colour makes more sense for you, in Processing you just go

```
hex(img.get(x,y))
```

and you get the same number in a more comprehensible form i.e FF618790

You can also extract the values of the colours themselves doing it either [the easy way](http://processing.org/reference/red_.html):

```
int a = alpha(img.get(x,y));
int r = red(img.get(x,y));
int g = green(img.get(x,y));
int b = blue(img.get(x,y));
```

or [the hard way](http://processing.org/reference/rightshift.html):

```
int a = (argb >> 24) & 0xFF;
int r = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF; 
int g = (argb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = argb & 0xFF;
```